# Изменить меню приложения

Tags: c#, uiautomation

Можно ли с помощью WinApi или UIAutomation изменять названия пунктов меню стороннего приложения (WPF)?

Comment: Хм. Вряд ли. А зачем такое нужно?

Comment: Слишком широкие названия пунктов меню. Надо бы покороче сделать, чтобы уменьшить минимально комфортную ширину окна приложения.

На winforms такое без проблем а с WPF проблемы

Comment: Так это надо делать разработчикам приложения, а не вам подставлять костыль. В UI Automation я такого не видел, его цель — автоматизировать то, что делает пользователь. А WinAPI тут скорее всего тоже не поможет, т. к. WPF-приложение не использует отдельные окна для пунктов меню.

Comment: @VladD, Может быть возможно каким-то образом подменить XAML/BAML в сборке?

Comment: @Андрей: Ну это, кстати, можно, да. ILSpy умеет просматривать, а при помощи Mono.Cecil можно, кажется, и подменить тоже.